# Strange behavior from an Application under IIS8

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis

i´m getting some problem here. My task was to transfer an old Application from an older server to a newer. After some configuration everything was fine, until I notice that the Application doesn´t want to work anymore.

Well I can Login and download files, that´s work perfect, but if I try to upload some files, everything start to go wrong. Even if I restart the server or recycle the Application-Pool, I can´t upload anymore.

What I found is, if I open a browser direct in the server and try to login and upload some file via localhost, the application start to working and just after that it is possible to use it an any oder PC, but just for some time, like 20 min and after that doesn´t work anymore...

I´m really confuse about that, because like I say, I can login and download files (anytime), but if I try to upload something, I have to go first to the server and run via localhost the aplication and just after that start working...

The server is a new 2012 with IIS8, running under .Net 4.5 classic(when I choose Integrated it doesn´t work at all).

This is part of the HTTP log:

```
#Software: Microsoft HTTP API 2.0
#Version: 1.0
#Date: 2013-06-25 16:28:18
#Fields: date time c-ip c-port s-ip s-port cs-version cs-method cs-uri sc-status s-siteid s-reason s-queuename
2013-06-25 16:28:18 ::1%0 49188 ::1%0 80 - - - - - Timer_ConnectionIdle -
2013-06-25 16:28:18 ::1%0 49196 ::1%0 80 - - - - - Timer_ConnectionIdle -
2013-06-25 16:28:22 ::1%0 49197 ::1%0 80 - - - - - Timer_ConnectionIdle -
2013-06-25 16:29:18 24.134.210.170 52690 10.10.10.100 80 HTTP/1.1 POST /DownloadManager/DMUpload.aspx?folderId=22767&guid=612219520&cancel=1 - 1 Timer_ConnectionIdle .NET+v4.5+Classic
2013-06-25 16:31:24 24.134.210.170 52693 10.10.10.100 80 - - - - - Timer_ConnectionIdle -
2013-06-25 16:31:29 24.134.210.170 52750 10.10.10.100 80 - - - - - Timer_ConnectionIdle -
2013-06-25 16:31:29 24.134.210.170 52749 10.10.10.100 80 - - - - - Timer_ConnectionIdle -
2013-06-25 16:33:39 ::1%0 49201 ::1%0 80 - - - - - Timer_ConnectionIdle -
2013-06-25 16:33:49 ::1%0 49212 ::1%0 80 - - - - - Timer_ConnectionIdle -
2013-06-25 16:33:54 ::1%0 49213 ::1%0 80 - - - - - Timer_ConnectionIdle -
2013-06-25 16:34:10 24.134.210.170 52766 10.10.10.100 80 - - - - - Timer_ConnectionIdle -
2013-06-25 16:37:46 24.134.210.170 52799 10.10.10.100 80 - - - - - Timer_ConnectionIdle -
2013-06-25 16:37:46 24.134.210.170 52767 10.10.10.100 80 - - - - - Timer_ConnectionIdle -
2013-06-25 16:37:46 24.134.210.170 52764 10.10.10.100 80 - - - - - Timer_ConnectionIdle -
2013-06-25 16:37:46 24.134.210.170 52794 10.10.10.100 80 - - - - - Timer_ConnectionIdle -
2013-06-25 16:47:48 24.134.210.170 52916 10.10.10.100 80 - - - - - Timer_ConnectionIdle -
2013-06-25 16:47:54 24.134.210.170 52917 10.10.10.100 80 - - - - - Timer_ConnectionIdle -
2013-06-25 17:00:27 24.134.210.170 53004 10.10.10.100 80 - - - - - Timer_ConnectionIdle -
2013-06-25 17:12:26 24.134.210.170 53123 10.10.10.100 80 - - - - - Timer_ConnectionIdle -
2013-06-25 17:12:31 24.134.210.170 53124 10.10.10.100 80 - - - - - Timer_ConnectionIdle -
2013-06-25 17:12:31 24.134.210.170 53126 10.10.10.100 80 - - - - - Timer_ConnectionIdle -
2013-06-25 17:13:04 24.134.210.170 53152 10.10.10.100 80 HTTP/1.1 POST /DownloadManager/DMUpload.aspx?folderId=22767&guid=289442538&cancel=1 400 1 BadRequest .NET+v4.5+Classic
2013-06-25 17:13:21 24.134.210.170 53152 10.10.10.100 80 HTTP/1.1 POST /DownloadManager/DMUpload.aspx?folderId=22767&guid=289442538&cancel=1 400 1 Connection_Dropped .NET+v4.5+Classic
2013-06-25 17:15:50 24.134.210.170 53161 10.10.10.100 80 HTTP/1.1 POST /DownloadManager/DMUpload.aspx?folderId=22767&guid=536693230&cancel=1 400 1 BadRequest .NET+v4.5+Classic
2013-06-25 17:16:00 24.134.210.170 53157 10.10.10.100 80 - - - - - Timer_ConnectionIdle -
2013-06-25 17:16:47 24.134.210.170 53161 10.10.10.100 80 HTTP/1.1 POST /DownloadManager/DMUpload.aspx?folderId=22767&guid=536693230&cancel=1 400 1 Connection_Dropped .NET+v4.5+Classic
2013-06-25 17:24:00 24.134.210.170 53160 10.10.10.100 80 - - - - - Timer_ConnectionIdle -
2013-06-25 17:24:05 24.134.210.170 53176 10.10.10.100 80 - - - - - Timer_ConnectionIdle -
2013-06-25 17:27:16 ::1%0 49251 ::1%0 80 - - - - - Timer_ConnectionIdle -
2013-06-25 17:27:31 24.134.210.170 53274 10.10.10.100 80 - - - - - Timer_ConnectionIdle -
2013-06-25 17:29:55 24.134.210.170 53291 10.10.10.100 80 - - - - - Timer_ConnectionIdle -
2013-06-25 17:29:55 24.134.210.170 53290 10.10.10.100 80 - - - - - Timer_ConnectionIdle -
2013-06-25 17:29:55 24.134.210.170 53292 10.10.10.100 80 - - - - - Timer_ConnectionIdle -
2013-06-25 17:32:17 24.134.210.170 53319 10.10.10.100 80 - - - - - Timer_ConnectionIdle -
2013-06-25 17:32:52 24.134.210.170 53293 10.10.10.100 80 - - - - - Timer_ConnectionIdle -
2013-06-25 17:32:52 24.134.210.170 53288 10.10.10.100 80 - - - - - Timer_ConnectionIdle -
```

I really apreciate some help, because I really don´t understand why this hapend. Really weird that I have to start the aplication direct in the server, before I can use it in other pc...

...Edit...

Ok here is the web.config from the aplication:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <section name="UploadModuleManagement" type="DimpleSoftwares.KFileUploadPlus.UploadModule,DimpleSoftwares.KFileUploadPlus" />
    </configSections>
    <UploadModuleManagement bufferSize="2000" />    
    <appSettings>       
        <add key="TempDir" value="./uploads" />             
    </appSettings>
    <system.web>
        <pages enableEventValidation="false" validateRequest="false" />
        <httpHandlers>
            <add verb="GET" path="FtbWebResource.axd" type="FreeTextBoxControls.AssemblyResourceHandler, FreeTextBox" />
        </httpHandlers>
        <httpModules>
            <add name="UploadModule" type="DimpleSoftwares.KFileUploadPlus.UploadModule,DimpleSoftwares.KFileUploadPlus" />
        </httpModules>
        <compilation defaultLanguage="c#" debug="true" />
    <customErrors mode="off" />                                       
        <authentication mode="Forms">
            <forms name="DMAuthCookie" loginUrl="DMLogin.aspx" protection="All" timeout="240" slidingExpiration="true" />
        </authentication>
        <authorization>
            <deny users="?" />
        </authorization>
        <trace enabled="false" requestLimit="10" pageOutput="false" traceMode="SortByTime" localOnly="true" />
        <sessionState mode="InProc" stateConnectionString="tcpip=127.0.0.1:42424" sqlConnectionString="data source=127.0.0.1;Trusted_Connection=yes" cookieless="false" timeout="240" />
        <globalization requestEncoding="utf-8" responseEncoding="utf-8" />
        <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="1048576" executionTimeout="14400" />
    </system.web>
    <system.webServer>
        <security>
          <requestFiltering>
            <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="1073741824" />
          </requestFiltering>
        </security>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

And this is the upload file:

```
<%@ Page language="c#" Codebehind="DMUpload.aspx.cs" AutoEventWireup="false" Inherits="DownloadManager.DMUpload" EnableSessionState="ReadOnly"%>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" >
<HTML>
  <HEAD>
        <title>DMUpload</title>
        <meta content="Microsoft Visual Studio .NET 7.1" name="GENERATOR">
        <meta content="C#" name="CODE_LANGUAGE">
        <meta content="JavaScript" name="vs_defaultClientScript">
        <meta content="http://schemas.microsoft.com/intellisense/ie5" name="vs_targetSchema">
        <LINK href="StyleSheet.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
  </HEAD>
    <body MS_POSITIONING="GridLayout">
        <form id="Form1" onSubmit="uploadpop(this);" method="post" encType="multipart/form-data" runat="server">
            <TABLE class="navigation" id="tbNavigation" cellSpacing="0" cellPadding="0" width="100%" border="0">
                <TR>
                    <TD align="right">
          <asp:panel id="Panel4" runat="server" CssClass="panelButtons" Width="800px">
          <asp:button id=btSave tabIndex=3 runat="server" CssClass="butt" Text="Save"></asp:button>
          <asp:button id=btBack tabIndex=3 runat="server" CssClass="butt" Text="back"></asp:button>
          <asp:button id=btLogout tabIndex=3 runat="server" CssClass="butt" Text="Logout"></asp:button>
                    </asp:panel>
          </TD>
                </TR>
                <tr>
                    <TD align="left">
            <asp:panel id="Panel1" runat="server" CssClass="panelBreadcrumb"></asp:panel>
            <asp:label id="lbBreadCrumb" runat="server" Font-Bold="True"></asp:label>
          </TD>
                </tr>
            </TABLE>
            <asp:label id="lbWarten" style="Z-INDEX: 103; LEFT: 24px; POSITION: absolute; TOP: 248px" runat="server" Height="40px" ForeColor="Red" Font-Size="Medium" Width="536px">please wait...</asp:label>
      <asp:panel id="panelUpload" style="Z-INDEX: 104; LEFT: 24px; POSITION: absolute; TOP: 96px" runat="server" Height="104px" Width="528px">
      <asp:label id=Label1 runat="server" Width="304px">File:</asp:label>
        <INPUT id=uploadFile1 style="WIDTH: 536px; HEIGHT: 22px" type=file size=70 runat="server">
        <INPUT id=uploadFile2 style="WIDTH: 536px; HEIGHT: 22px" type=file size=70 runat="server">
        <INPUT id=uploadFile3 style="WIDTH: 536px; HEIGHT: 22px" type=file size=70 runat="server">
        <INPUT id=uploadFile4 style="WIDTH: 536px; HEIGHT: 22px" type=file size=70 runat="server">
        <INPUT id=uploadFile5 style="WIDTH: 536px; HEIGHT: 22px" type=file size=70 runat="server">
            </asp:panel>
    </form>
        <script language="javascript">

            document.getElementById("lbWarten").style.visibility = "hidden";

            function uploadpop(inForm)
            {
                document.getElementById("lbWarten").style.visibility = "visible";

                if(inForm.uploadFile1 != null)
                {
                    if(    inForm.uploadFile1.value !="" 
                        || inForm.uploadFile2.value !="" 
                        || inForm.uploadFile3.value !="" 
                        || inForm.uploadFile4.value !="" 
                        || inForm.uploadFile5.value !="")
                    {
                        strUniqueID = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000000) * ((new Date()).getTime() % 1000);                
                        thePos = inForm.action.indexOf("?");
/*
                        if (thePos >= 0)
                            inForm.action = inForm.action.substring(0, thePos);
                        inForm.action += "?guid=" + strUniqueID + "&cancel=1";
*/
                        if (thePos >= 0)
                            inForm.action += "&guid=" + strUniqueID + "&cancel=1";
                        else
                            inForm.action += "?guid=" + strUniqueID + "&cancel=1";

                        window.open("DMProgressBar.aspx?guid=" + strUniqueID,"","toolbar=0,scrollbars=0,location=0,status=0,menubar=0,resizable=0,height=275,width=600,top=70,left=100");
                    }
                }               
                inForm.submit();
                return true;
            }

            function ClearInput()
            {
                node = document.getElementById("panelUpload");
                if(node != null)
                {
//                  node.removeNode(true);
                    node.parentNode.removeChild(node);
                }
                return true;
            }

        </script>
    </body>
</HTML>
```

Comment: You need to give some details about what the code is doing and how it is doing it.

Comment: This log is not help at all. What is your web.config, did the pool is the same version with the app ? did you have correctly set the file permissions, can you run a simple test page ?

Comment: You should be more specific about what's not working. Is the upload popup not working? Are you getting an HTTP error?

Comment: When it works, appear a popup window showing the file name, remaining time, etc.
When it doesn´t, appear a blank popup window and after a time the browser show a blank page with: www.website.com/DownloadManager/DMUpload.aspx?folderId=22767&guid=324327780&cancel=1

It doesn´t go back to the main page, just a white page.

I know it "works" because if I see the Temporal folder, I see that a file is saved, but it´s not moved to the final destination.

Comment: As I wrote: I can login, delete files, download files. It´s just when I try to upload some files it doesn´t work. I already try to refresh or recycle the Application and the Pool, without success. The only way to mke it work is when i go to the server, open IIS, open the aplication and select browser the aplication. Then I have to login and try to upload some file, just after that start working in any other PC(Browser).

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think it´s working now. I change some settings in the upload file:

```
<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="1048576" executionTimeout="14400" />
```

The executionTimeout was too high, I just reduce to 45 sec and extend in the IIS the sessiontime.

Until now works and hope stay like that!

Comment: I am not sure if this is a solution as execution timeout will only give you are failed response faster in case of a failure. That is it will only let you execute the request within a 45 sec window.

Comment: And how can I trace the failures? Now I´m not pretty sure if it the php or the application itself.. The thing is, why I have some timeouts and sometime not....